# WordCloud is not removing custom stopwords

Tags: python, word-cloud, stop-words

I am trying to add stopwords to be removed from my word clouds. It seems that all of a sudden, my additional stopwords are not being added. It was working before.

I have boiled down the problem to what is shown here along with the first word cloud from the loop. You can see at the top that the word "product" is still present even though I added it to the list of stopwords. The other two stopwords were properly removed. I have collocations set to False.

I tried with version 1.5.0 and 1.6.0

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import pandas as pd
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

for i in range(20):
  print(i)
  wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=["product", "and", "the"], background_color='white', collocations=False).generate(clusterStrings[i])
  # Display the generated image:
  plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
  plt.axis("off")
  plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are creating a new instance on each loop, plus you are replacing instead of adding additional stopwords. Try create wc and adding stopwords to the known STOPWORDS outside your loop

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import pandas as pd
import collections
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

...
# create the instance only once and add stopwords
stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
stopwords.add(["product", "and", "the"])

wordcloud = WordCloud(stopwords=stopwords, background_color='white', collocations=False)

for i in range(20):
  print(i)
  wordcloud.generate(clusterStrings[i])
  # Display the generated image:
  plt.imshow(wordcloud, interpolation='bilinear')
  plt.axis("off")
  plt.show()
```

Comment: I was adding to the original stopwords initially. I just changed the code to this to show that one of the three explicit stopwords is still showing up. I tried your code, but only with adding "product" to the set. But "product" still shows up.

Comment: They is very strange. Try search "product" in clusterString and check if there are hidden space e.g. "product ". Another, get the clusterString with product and check `"product" in clusterString[x]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:
(Reference)

```
from wordcloud import WordCloud, STOPWORDS
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def plot_wordcloud(text, mask=None, max_words=200, max_font_size=100, figure_size=(24.0,16.0), 
                   title = None, title_size=40, image_color=False):
    stopwords = set(STOPWORDS)
    more_stopwords = {'one', 'br', 'Po', 'th', 'sayi', 'fo', 'Unknown'}
    stopwords = stopwords.union(more_stopwords)

    wordcloud = WordCloud(background_color='black',
                    stopwords = stopwords,
                    max_words = max_words,
                    max_font_size = max_font_size, 
                    random_state = 42,
                    width=800, 
                    height=400,
                    mask = mask)
    wordcloud.generate(str(text))
    
    plt.figure(figsize=figure_size)
    if image_color:
        image_colors = ImageColorGenerator(mask);
        plt.imshow(wordcloud.recolor(color_func=image_colors), interpolation="bilinear");
        plt.title(title, fontdict={'size': title_size,  
                                  'verticalalignment': 'bottom'})
    else:
        plt.imshow(wordcloud);
        plt.title(title, fontdict={'size': title_size, 'color': 'black', 
                                  'verticalalignment': 'bottom'})
    plt.axis('off');
    plt.tight_layout()  
    
plot_wordcloud(train_df["Col_name"], title="Word Cloud of ...")
```

Comment: Tried this code, but still get the word "product" showing up after adding it to the stopwords.

Comment: Also, make sure you tokenize your file so that it all gets broken up word-by-word.

Comment: Use `split()` and `' '.join()` so it will remove any unnecessary spaces in between